# NoClassDefFoundError in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError in a ServletException, in the second of these lines:

```
List items;
items = servlet_up.parseRequest(request);
```

I was looking for it, and from [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) I think I've understood the situation, but not the solution.

In [how to fix NoClassDefFoundError in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143867/how-to-fix-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) Alvaro said that We can import the library that is missing to fix it, but since:

1.- I don't know which library is it for me (maybe the servlet-api.jar?)

2.- It's a JSP and not a Java Class (I mean, I don't compile it, so I don't know which jar is it using)

3.- Where should I put the jar at the end? In the `./lib/` folder of the JSP App?

So that's it, I don't really know how to proceed.

Thank you in advance!

**Update**: It's not a problem with `List` class, since the problem is in the second line where List has been already used.

Besides, I've the following imports:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
```

Finally, what I'm getting at runtime is (I'll delete some lines that are comments on the code to make it shorter):

```
type Informe de Excepción
mensaje
descripción El servidor encontró un error interno () que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
excepción

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /uploadFile.jsp en línea 39

37:   ServletFileUpload servlet_up = new ServletFileUpload(file_factory);
39:   List items = servlet_up.parseRequest(request);

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

causa raíz

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
org.apache.jsp.uploadFile_jsp._jspService(uploadFile_jsp.java:137)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

causa raíz

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:123)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:617)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:634)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1023)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:1003)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
org.apache.jsp.uploadFile_jsp._jspService(uploadFile_jsp.java:97)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Can you add the exact exception trace to your question :) ?

Comment: Added imports and stack trace. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should place your JAR containing `IOUtils` inside WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: did you added commons io jars to the lib folder in WEB-INF?

Comment: `IOUtils` class can be found in `commons-io-2.1.jar`. No need to use exactly 2.1, you can use any other version available to you :)

Comment: I didn't! I'm gonna try it right now. Thanks you all so much!

Comment: I seriously suggest you to use Maven/Gradle so that you don't have to worry about all these dependencies. You'll just add your main dependency in your pom.xml and everything else will be downloaded and added to your target WAR.

Comment: It should be useful, but I was already using Eclipse and at the end, I had more problems with it than with my application. At the end, I switched to manual mode XD

Comment: Spend some more time on Maven/Gradle. Once you understand them better you can save lot of time avoiding these common mistakes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your exception stack trace, it's clear that you're missing `org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils` class in Class Path. So add `commons-io-2.4.jar` (not necessarily 2.4, it can be any other version) to your WEB-INF/lib directory.

You can find all the JARs in Maven Repository [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io)